# select the value on dropdown then display the edit form with php,ajax,jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a form

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <select id="groups">
    <optgroup label="GroupA">
    <option value="2">[GroupA]  value1</option>
    <option value="11">[GroupA] value2</option>
    <option value="14">[GroupA] value3</option>
    <option value="15">[GroupA] value4</option>
    <option value="601">[GroupA] value5</option>
    <option value="21">[GroupA] value6</option>
    <option value="23">[GroupA] value7</option>
    <option value="24">[GroupA] value8</option> 
    </optgroup>
    ...
 </select>
</form>
<br />
<div id="txtHint"><b>Show edit form here.</b></div>

</body>
</html>
```

When user selecte value from dropdown list ,the  edit form will appear 
the edit value will query by using seleted value.
Anyone can help me to do this with php,ajax, jquery?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by *the edit value will query by using selected value?*

Comment: did you forgot the <select>..</select> ?

Comment: Please use the search function of this site. It might take some time, but you should find tons of AJAX and dropdown examples. Tons.

Comment: Let me tell you how this site works: You write the code, and we help if you really can't solve it (and when you ask the question, you show your existing code and where you think the problem is). You will never be able to write this if you don't keep trying. So this "I have these requirements, write this for me plzplz" should not happen. Voted to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mmm, maybe you can try with:

```
$("select#idOfYourSelectElement").change(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax/myphpajax.php",
        data: "acction=loadForm&selectedElement=" + $(this).val(),
        async: false,
        success: function(htmlWithNewForm){
            $("div#txtHint").html(htmlWithNewForm);
            //if the div is hidden
            $("div#txtHint").css("visibility","visible");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: what is htmlWithNewForm here? can you more clear please? thanks

Comment: The HTML response with the form.

Answer (score 1):

To get the selected value of a dropdown / select box, which should be added around the  element, can be got using jQuery like so:

```
<select id="groups">
  <optgroup label="GroupA"> 
    <option value="2">[GroupA]  value1</option>
    ....
  </optgroup>
</select>

$(function() {
  $("#groups").change(function() {
      var selectedValue = this.val();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are quite a few ways to do this.

One way is to set up a url that you can hit with the value that returns an HTML fragment based on the select drop down value.

The basic flow would be:

Javascript code:

```
$('select_id_here').change(function() {
  var url = "path_here/to_something
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "get",
    data: {
      "value": this.val()
    }
}).done(function(html) {
  $('txtHint').html(html)
});
```

PHP controller would have a function that handles the url that you are calling and returns html according to the value. How you do this, depends on the framework you are using.

```
function handle_to_something() {
  $value = $_GET['value']; // horrible to use GET array
  $html = render("path/to/template/$value.html");
  return $html;
}
```